# Insert '\0' in the middle of the string has no effect (C++)

Tags: c++, string

I have a string and tried inserting '\0' in the kth position (where k < n & n is the length of the string). After inserting '\0' in the 3rd position and tried displaying the string. I am getting the entire string but I expected only the portion before '\0' ? Am I right ? Or is there anything special about c++ strings??

Say for example :

```
// My string is as below

string s = "wabcdddeefff"; 

// After inserting '\0' in the 3rd position and tried displaying the string showed the entire string unchanged.
// Will the string now become s = "wab" ??
```

To be more clear. I have posted my code .

```
string s="wwwwaaadexxxxxx";
int l = s.size();
int k = 1;
char a = s[0];
int count = 1;

for(int i=1; i<l; i++)  {
    if(s[i] == a)   {
        count++;    // cout << "\nS["<<i<<"] " << s[i] << " Count " << count;
    }
    else    {
        if(count == 1)  {
            s[k++] = s[i];
        }
        else    {
            s[k++] = count+'0';     //cout << "\n     s["<<k<<"] " << s[k-1] << "count " << count;
            s[k++] = s[i];
        }
        a = s[i];
        count = 1;       //cout << "\nCount " << count << " a " << a;
    }

}  


if(count > 1)
    s[k++] = count+'0';

s[k++] = '\0';
cout << "\n \n String "  << s << endl;
```

FYU, I've attached the console screen shot :)

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just write some code where you insert `'\0'` in the middle of a string and print it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assuming that C++ `std::string`s work just like null-terminated C-strings.

They don't.

C++ `std::string`s are length-aware containers of `char` and are, in general, binary-safe. That means you can store arbitrary `char`s in it and not break anything. This is incredibly useful, because now you can store arbitrary data, including strings that might be, at higher levels of abstraction, in a Unicode representation. Or the data may be binary-encoded information.

The only way you can "break" a `std::string` in the manner you expect is to obtain a pointer to the underlying buffer (i.e. a `const char*`, via `std::string::c_str()`) and treat it as a C-string which, by necessity, is considered to be null-terminated by all the C library functions you're then likely to use, including those responsible for output.

The sort of logic you are trying to implement here is a C idiom, taking advantage of that limitation of C strings. It does not translate verbatim into C++ when you use modern "containers".<sup>1</sup>

If you wish to truncate a `std::string`, simply call the member function `std::string::resize` on it:

```
s.resize(k);
```

You'll thank me for it later.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Technically, `std::string` is not a container in standard library parlance. However, in the general sense, it's a thing that contains other things, so…</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot lot for your explanation !!

Comment: @Steve: No problem, and congratulations on your resurrection.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` doesn't need a null terminator, use C strings `const char*` to get the desired output.

Or print out the string with `c_str()`.

Comment: Okie !! But can I achieve my goal using **string** itself ??

Comment: @SteveJobs print it out using `yourstring.c_str();`

Comment: Got it .. Thanks a lot !! Sry folks Completely new to c++ !!

Comment: Unfortunately, Jamey has sent you in the wrong direction. You started with C-like C++ and now it's even more C-like.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Merely answered the question.

Comment: Except you didn't, because you can't inject an `'\0`' into a C-string through a `const char*`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He asked how strings work with null terminators. I didn't expect a reply on my comment 2,5 months later.

Comment: Why does it matter how long it's been? This answer still exists so its quality is still of relevance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True, it's just a bit unusual for me. Anyways, your (better) answer which explains it more thoroughly has been accepted instead of mine so does it's relevance still matter? I wouldn't say so.

Comment: Yes, of course it does. Questions on Stack Exchange websites are not just for the person who posted them. This is a Q&A. The questions and answers remain around forever, for the benefit of others.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand that. Perhaps I wasn't clear in what I said. What I meant was that your answer is the correct answer and it's better than mine. It has more upvotes and is accepted which means that people that will check out this question will scroll down to your answer and most of the time just disregard my answer because yours is the better one (more upvotes and accepted). So doesn't that mean that the quality of my answer is less important?